# How can I pop from a Redis sorted set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I'm using a Redis sorted set as a queue to maintain a list of users and I need to pop the first item in the list and use it, but I'm having issues. Here's my attempt...

```
keys = []
$redis.multi do
    # Get the item at the top of the sorted set
    keys = $redis.zrange("users:waiting", 0, 0)

    # Remove it from the set
    $redis.zrem("users:waiting", keys[0])
end

# Get the item from the range
@user_id = keys[0]
```

...but this code just doesn't work. Help! Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not work is because of MULTI.

keys is not assigned. The call to EXEC which happens at end is when these results are returned

See https://github.com/redis/redis-rb#executing-commands-atomically

and just below it https://github.com/redis/redis-rb#futures

Should show the difference :) Apologies if this is not entirely correct as I don't use Ruby.